# Pandas - Counting quantity of commas in character field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column filled with strings as is shown below:

```
   string_column
0  t,d,t,d,v,d
1  s,v,y,d
2  d,u,f
```

I would like to create a new column with the count of commas in the string column. My intended outcome is below:

```
   string_column  comma_count
0  t,d,t,d,v,d    5
1  s,v,y,d        3
2  d,u,f          2
```

Is there a string reading method to pandas that will accomplish this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['comma_count'] = df.string_column.str.count(',')
print (df)
  string_column  comma_count
0   t,d,t,d,v,d            5
1       s,v,y,d            3
2         d,u,f            2
```

Comment: It is not counting the exact number it is stripping the first value.

Answer (score 5):

use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html)

```
df.assign(comma_count=df.string_column.str.count(','))

  string_column  comma_count
0   t,d,t,d,v,d            5
1       s,v,y,d            3
2         d,u,f            2
```